# Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Form\TagType::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository, none given,

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am using `EntityType` field to create a multiple select dropdown. Also I want to query the available options based on user input (eg. `standard`), and then display the options.
For this, I am trying to inject EntityRepository into my TagType form itself, so that I can use it's `CreateQueryBuilder`. But I get this error -

[image]

Here is my code, `TagType.php`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

class TagType extends AbstractType {

    protected $er;

    public function __construct(EntityRepository $er)
    {
        $this->er = $er;
    }

    private function getTagsByCategoryName($categoryname, $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('t')
                ->innerJoin('t.categories', 'c', 'WITH', 'c.categoryname = :categoryname')
                ->setParameter('categoryname', $categoryname)
                ->orderBy('t.id', 'ASC');
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('tagname', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Tag',
            'choices' => $this->getTagsByCategoryName('standard'),
            'choice_label' => 'tagname',
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => true,
            'label' => 'Choose Tags',
        ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Tag',
            'tags' => null,
        ));
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

2 answers:

- You don't need to inject `EntityRepository` into your Form to use `query_builder` option of `EntityType`. `EntityType` will inject the `EntityRepository` on your behalf, you just need to define a method taking `EntityRepository` as parameter. Knowing this:

  ```
  class TagType extends AbstractType
  {    
      private function getTagsByCategoryName($categoryname) {
          return function(EntityRepository $er) {
              return $er->createQueryBuilder('t')
              ->innerJoin('t.categories', 'c', 'WITH', 'c.categoryname = :categoryname')
              ->setParameter('categoryname', $categoryname)
              ->orderBy('t.id', 'ASC');
          }
      }

      public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
          $builder->add('tagname', EntityType::class, array(
              'class' => 'AppBundle:Tag',
              'choices' => $this->getTagsByCategoryName('standard'),
              'choice_label' => 'tagname',
              'expanded' => false,
              'multiple' => true,
              'label' => 'Choose Tags',
          ));
      }

      public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
          $resolver->setDefaults(array(
              'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Tag',
              'tags' => null,
          ));
      }
  }
  ```

should be enough.

- If you ever really need to inject a service inside your Form, use [DependencyInjection](http://symfony.com/doc/master//components/dependency_injection/types.html).